# SQL Server syntax for Insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I know the syntax below isn't correct, but was hoping someone could tell me what the correct syntax for this in SQL Server would be:

```
INSERT INTO TBL1 (SELECT * FROM TBL2 WHERE PK not in (SELECT PK FROM TBL1))
```

**TBL1** and **TBL2** are both identical as far as columns and data types are concerned.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? They should always be your first port of call.

Comment: Best practice is to always list the columns being inserted and the columns being selected. This prevents a lot of potential issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses after the table name in `insert` are where the columns should be.  You can express this without the parens:

```
INSERT INTO TBL1
    SELECT *
    FROM TBL2
    WHERE PK NOT IN (SELECT PK FROM TBL1);
```

Or follow the best practice and list the columns:

```
INSERT INTO TBL1 (col1, col2, col3, . . . )
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, . . . 
    FROM TBL2
    WHERE PK NOT IN (SELECT PK FROM TBL1);
```